# Integrating remote validation with HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a form that uses HTML5 validation and I want to incorporate some remote validation into it.  Here is the relevant HTML and Javascript generated on my page :

```
<form action="/en-GB/Main/UserAdd" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-remote="&#39;Username&#39; is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Username" data-val-remote-url="/en-GB/Validation/IsUsernameAvailable" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" required="true" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required="true" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Surname field is required." id="Surname" name="Surname" required="true" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Country">Country</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CountryId must be a number." data-val-required="The CountryId field is required." id="CountryId" name="CountryId"><option value="1">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="2">Republic of Ireland</option>
<option value="3">Australia</option>
<option value="4">New Zealand</option>
<option value="5">United States</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add User" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //set up buttons
            $(function () {
                $("input:submit").button();
            });

            var elementsInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (var i = 0; i < elementsInput.length; i++) {

                elementsInput[i].oninvalid = function (e) {

                    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {

                        switch (e.target.name) {

                            case "Username":
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Username");
                                break;

                            case "FirstName":
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a First Name");
                                break;

                            case "Surname":
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a Surname");
                                    break;
                    }
                }
                    };
            elementsInput[i].oninput = function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            };
        }


        });

        </script>
```

Is it possible to incorporate the data-val-remote attributes into my javascript so that I can show the validation message from this in my HTML5 validation?

EDIT : Here is my remote validation class :

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    IMainRepository _repository;

    public ValidationController() : this(new MainRepository())
    {
    }

    public ValidationController(IMainRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public static string GetAltName(string Username, IMainRepository repository)
    {

        string suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} is not available.", Username);

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string altCandidate = Username + i.ToString();
            if (!repository.UsernameExists(altCandidate))
            {
                suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               "{0} is not available. Try {1}.", Username, altCandidate);
                break;
            }
        }

        return suggestedUID;
    }

    public JsonResult IsUsernameAvailable(string Username)
    {

        if (!_repository.UsernameExists(Username))
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        string suggestedUID = GetAltName(Username, _repository);
        return Json(suggestedUID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I don't see why you couldn't roll some services that return validity of an input based upon an attribute. Are you asking us to write that for you?

Comment: I have only just started to use HTML 5 and was hoping for a few pointers. I have written the method that creates the data-val-remote attribute but now I need to find out how I can check against it in my javascript.

Comment: Ok, so you've written /en-GB/Validation/IsUsernameAvailable?  Could you update your question with this?

Comment: I'd recommend breaking the question down to the lowest level necessary if you want to get an answer. Use a form with one example input, the validation javascript/jquery you are currently using, and what you are hoping for it to do.  It's difficult for us to read through one big block of html.

Comment: I have removed everything apart from the generated form and javascript to make it a bit more readable

Comment: I can't spend much time on this right now, but believe I can help.  In the meantime, I'd look at this tutorial to see if you can make progress. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx

Comment: It doesn't look like you should have to do anything different for HTML5 vs regular HTML.  Have you seen this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Let's start by verifying your validation controller with Firebug.  Download and install it and then test /en-GB/Validation/IsUsernameAvailable?Username=Testname  What is the result?  What if you put a name that exists?

Comment: The remote validation works if I have a ValidationMessageFor element on the page. My question is to do with integrating it into HTML 5 popup validation, so I remove the ValidationMessageFor and want to somehow make reference to it in my Javascript so that I can check if the remote validation failed and if so use the error message with e.target.setCustomValidity(). I want to know if this is possible and if so what syntax to use in my Javascript.

Comment: I have written a plugin for [HTML5 validation with remote validation](https://www.annytab.com/html5-form-validation-with-javascript/) in a blog post.